# java - unix & windows file writing with least effort

Tags: java, unix

I have a java web aplication, that i am required to move from a windows based machine, to unix.
in my application i do a lot of file writing, and as i didn't forsee that request when i originally wrote the code (and lack of expirience obviously..), i've created different classes, with each class dictating it's own output paths when writing content to files.

the way i see it, the ideal solution would be to have a file handler with a static variable of path delimiter that would be set to "\" if windows else "/"

problem is, that implementing the above would currently be painfull and time consuming, as i currently have several class that create output paths on their own (String path = "C:\path\" + variable + ".tsv ...etc)

does anyone has any creative idea for adjusting the code to be compatible with unix without much effort?

also, are there any other differences that i should take into consideration?

Comment: Java does that.  Except is uses "/" as the generic stand-in for file path separators, not "\".

Comment: I agree with @markspace. If you need to care about the path character, you can call File.pathSeparator

Comment: @lordoku `File.pathSeparator` holds `:` on Linux & Unix and `;` on Windows

Comment: @msrd0 Yes, it's actually `File.separator` if you want '/' or '\'.

Comment: i didn't know that / is valid in windows, it actually solves my problem, as although i build paths in different classes, i do have a single static method that does the writing, so i'll do path.replaceAll("\\","/") before writing the output, thank you!

Comment: @msrd0 good catch. I meant to say File.separator

Comment: I'd suggest taking a loot at the `Path` class, and its associated helper methods, since this is what they're for.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/file/Paths.html

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy - either use an url (that has a `/` every time) or, and I would prefer that since you don't need to manipulate your code that much, use the static variables of `java.io.File` and the system properties, e.g. if you want to save a file in the temporary directory, use this `File` object (I'm aware that there is a predefined method to create a temporary file in Java, this is just an example):

```
File tmpFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tempdir")
        + File.separator + "filename");
```

In this case, it would be equivalent to:

```
File tmpFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tempdir"),
        "filename");
```